# Как сделать переадресацию на разные версии сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Нужно, чтобы после обновления страницы, происходила смена главной страницы `index.html`, на любую выбранную из списка.

Comment: слишком мало вводной информации, распишите подробнее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Вы можете сделать шаблоны, ваших главных страниц и подставлять по очереди или в случайном порядке, после обновления страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать функцию `mt_rand` с диапазоном числа от 0 до 1:

```
echo include(mt_rand(0,1) ? 'one.php' : 'two.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

вот решение сам нашел))) вас пока дождешься) Может быть кому то пригодится решение)))

```html
<?php

if(mt_rand(1, 2) == 1) {
        echo file_get_contents('http://sait/test1.html');
} else {
        echo file_get_contents('http://sait/test2.html');
}

?>
```

Comment: удручающее решение. Решение Bart было гораздо производительнее.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, использовать **куки**. Можно и с **записью значения в ini** файл:
(для получения ip подойдет [эта функция](https://pastebin.com/m3VX3bBy))

```
$data = parse_ini_file('./myfile.ini');
$pageNumber = $data[getAdress()]['page'];
echo file_get_contents('index-'.$pageNumber.'.html'); // Выводим страницу
```

Вместо IP можно использовать порядковые номера.
*Можно поместить обе страницы в один файл и заменить `file_get_contents` на переменную, которая будет устанавливаться условием (`if` либо `switch`).*

Для записи в INI файл можно использовать [эту функцию](https://pastebin.com/Kk0GA3B2).

```
// Пример использования
$iniData = parse_ini_file('./myfile.ini');
if($iniData[getAdress()]['page'] == 1) $iniData[getAdress()]['page'] = 0;
else $iniData[getAdress()]['page'] = 1;
file_put_contents('./myfile.ini', iniCreate($iniData)); // Записываем в файл
```

*Это, конечно, не самый лучший выход, но для небольшого проекта пойдет.*